# Why can't multiple chars be assignable in an array?

Tags: c

Take the following example of trying to do character assignment to an array:

```
char newer_string[3][6];
newer_string[0] = "One";
newer_string[0] = "Two";
newer_string[0] = "Three";
```

This fails with the following error:

```
main.c:46:18: error: array type 'char [6]' is not assignable
```

Why is it necessary to add each individual one-at-a-time, for example"

```
char newer_string[3][6];
newer_string[0][0] = 'O';
newer_string[0][1] = 'n';
// ...etc...
```

What's the most common way to "append" items to an empty array?

Additionally, perhaps I'm misunderstanding the need for a 2D array (or what it even is), because I can also do something like:

```
char *newer_string[3];
newer_string[0] = "One";
newer_string[1] = "Two!!!";
newer_string[2] = "Three";
```

What would be the best way to assign multiple "words" to an array (a 2D character array? or 1D string-pointer array?)

Comment: Either through *initialization*, use `memcpy` (or `strcpy` if a *nul-terminated* string is wanted), or loop assigning each char. You have to understand that `"One"` is a *String-Literal* and when assigned, you are assigning the address to the first character (which on most OSs will be in the `.rodata` (read-only) data segment). `newer_string` has type `char (*)[6]` (*pointer-to-array* of `char[6]`) when you dereference it using the `[..]` operator you are left with `char [6]` which you cannot fill an ARRAY by assignment.

Comment: With your edit, `char *newer_string[3];`, `newer_string` has type `char *[3]` (an *array of pointers* `[3]` -- e.g. an array of 3-pointers). You CAN assign the address of a *String-Literal* to a pointer. The types are compatible.

Comment: It's for historical reasons that are too late to change now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Type Controls Everything**

You cannot *assign" a string to an ARRAY. You can assign the address of a *String-Literal* to a pointer.

When you declare `char newer_string[3][6];` you declare a 2D array of `char` (an array of 1D arrays). You can *initialize* the contents of an array at the time of declaration, but thereafter, you cannot assign the contents of the array. When you attempt to assign the address of the *String-Literal* `"One"` to an array, your compiler properly throws the error:

```
main.c:46:18: error: array type 'char [6]' is not assignable
```

(your compiler is correct, you are attempting to assign type `char*` to `char[6]`)

Remember on access, except when used as the operand of `sizeof` or used to initialize an array, 6.3.2.1(p3) apples (see below) making a *String-Literal* type `char*` (which is a pointer to (the address of) the first character in the literal). A string-literal is immutable and any attempt to modify is *Undefined* [C11 Standard - 6.4.5 String literals(p7)](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.4.5p7), but a few non-conforming compilers provide for mutable string literals.

On access, your 2D array is converted to a pointer to the first 1D array. [C11 Standard - 6.3.2.1 Other Operands - Lvalues, arrays, and function designators(p3)](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.2.1p3) The type is `char (*)[6]` (*pointer-to-array* of `char[6]`). When you derefernce the pointer-to-array using the `[..]` operator, you are left with a simple array. You cannot assign the contents of an array.

To copy to the array, either use `memcpy` (or `strcpy` if a *nul-terminated* string is wanted), or loop over each index assigning each char.

**Your Array of Pointers**

With your edit, `char *newer_string[3];`, `newer_string` has type `char *[3]` (an *array of pointers* `[3]` -- e.g. an array of 3-pointers). You CAN assign the address of a *String-Literal* to a pointer. The types are compatible.

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: The type of `"ONE"` is not a `char*`, but is a `const char[4]`

Comment: Exactly string literal is an array and it is defined by the standard

Comment: Yes, granted, but for purpose of assignment to a pointer, it is a pointer to the first character in the literal if use anywhere other than for initialization.

Comment: @MateuszWojtczak - Wrong, read [C11 Standard - 6.3.2.1(p3)](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.2.1p3) again. The exception to conversion to pointer only applies when the literal is used to "*initialize an array*" -- the defined behavior as an initializer. Otherwise it is converted to a pointer to the first character.

Comment: Minor points: "a String-Literal is type char*" --> ??? A _string_literal_ is an array.  sizeof("xy") is certainly 3.  "A string-literal is immutable in most OSs" --> its is more of a compiler issues than an OS.

Comment: Yes, that is agreed, what was explained was the effective type for assignment. To which 6.3.2.1(p3) applies unless the string literal is used as the operand of the `sizeof` operator or to *initialize an array* which was the reason for the cite as neither of those conditions applied to the question as the string literal was not used as the operator of `sizeof` and was not used as an initializer (what was being attempted was the assignment of pointers)